# Renaming Package name in .java file too , android eclipse

Tags: android

I renamed the package name using Project -> Android Tools -> Rename Package Name , but after renaming ,package name is changed   in the AndroidManifest file only , and not in .java files . How can i change it everywhere

Comment: Which IDE you using?

Comment: The app package name is actually independent from the java class package names. Them being the same is just a common practice. If you want to change them according to the app package, do that in a second step (eclipse: select package in "Package Explorer" view, then hit F2, AS: no idea.)

Comment: F2 doesn't help , it just changes the project name in ide and not in .java files.If I decide not to touch .java files package name , from  now on I will have to write package oldname or package newname at the start of the file

Answer (score 1):

Best way to rename package is to right click the package name and click Rename. Don't Forget to check the options. Enable Update references.

Hope it will help.